# Make pdf created with mpdf more accessible

Tags: accessibility, mpdf

I'm using MPDF to create a nice looking PDF based on an online HTML magazine. But checking the PDF for accessibility shows me that the file doesn't have any tags, so screen readers see no content at all.

Is there a way to fix this? Best would be I can make it fully accessible but if this is not possible, the least I want is to show one text and an URL to the online accessible alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I agree. But I’m looking for a mpdf solution to output not all tags but any tag at all. I know this will not deliver an accessible pdf and I know how to make one with the adobe suite. But that’s not my goal and not my question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering its position in the PDFLib Market, mPDF (enhanced fPDF) only has first steps towards conformance, Which do not include any U-tagging.

> *"Important: mPDF is not guaranteed to produce fully PDF/A1-b compliant files in all circumstances. It is the users responsibility to check compliance if this is essential."*

> PDF/A-3 associated files + Additional XMP RDF
> It is possible to attach files “PDF/A-3” way (via “Associated Files” /AF key) and inject additional XMP RDF to the document metadata.

> *"Important: mPDF is not guaranteed to produce fully PDF/X-1a compliant files in all circumstances. It is the users responsibility to check compliance if this is essential."*

Thus as of current version 7 the basic levels (needing Manual Checks) are

- PDF/A-1b support (ISO 19005-1:2005)
- PDF/A-3 support (along with ZUGFeRD invoices compatibility)
- PDF/X-1a support

For generating PDF Ua see the commercial parent Apryse-PDFLib (from PDFTron/iText etc Group)

- Create Tagged PDF with Textflow where the tags are supplied inline in the text.
- Create combined PDF/UA-1 and PDF/A-2a invoice.

https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdfua/

In all such cases of building PDF/#/U files For Accessibility, you are more than likely to end up using Adobe paid products, to achieve final compliance. Thus best to start off with a Copy of Acrobat PRO, which has its own programming API.

> It’s a good idea to review all issues [ per page] to determine which ones require correction.
> https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html